# Polynomials ( Bezout's Theorem and Vieta's Formula)

Tags: polynomials

Another question for faculty entrance exam (workbook tasks).
Equation $x^3 + x^2 + ax + b = 0$ (a,b $\in R$) have solutions $1-\sqrt{2} $ and $1+ \sqrt{2}$. Product of all the available solutions of this equation is (answer is 3, but I need steps).
NOTICE : High School level please!
EDIT: I guess I have to use Vieta's Formula but I do not how promptly to use it.My brain is literally blocked on solving this one.

Comment: what is a faculty entrance exam?

Comment: Are you saying that you need our help to pass an entrance exam so that you can become a faculty member?

Comment: This is task from my preparation workbook and exam from 2008 or 2007, I'm not sure which one. My entrance exam is for 10 days and I need help mostly for polynomial and trigonometry questions.

Answer (score 2):

By one of the Vieta formulas, the sum of all the roots is $-1$. We know two of the roots, and can deduce that the third root is $-3$.

Now find the product $(1-\sqrt{2})(1+\sqrt{2})(-3)$.

Answer (score 0):

The third root of $p(x)$ has to be a real root, so the polynomial can be written as: $((x-1)^2-2)(x-c)=(x^2-2x-1)(x-c)=x^3-(c+2)x^2+(2c-1)x+c$. Equate the coefficients of $p(x)$ we have: $c+2 = -1 \to c = -3$, and the answer follows from Vieta's formula.